# right syntax to use near '%+ads.title+%\r\n AND\r\n products_request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to compare two columns by `like` :

```
    $sql = "SELECT
                products_requests.id as req_id,ads.id as send_id,
                products_requests.user_id,ads.des,ads.title

                FROM
                products_requests,ads

                WHERE
                  products_requests.title LIKE '%'+ads.title+'%'
                  AND
                  products_requests.ads_cat_id = ads.ads_cat_id
                  AND
                  products_requests.ads_sub_cat_id = ads.ads_sub_cat_id
                  AND
                  products_requests.price_type_id = ads.price_type_id
                  AND
                  products_requests.province_id = ads.province_id
                  AND
                  products_requests.city_id = ads.city_id";
```

but I get this error :

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%+ads.title+%\r\n AND\r\n products_request' at line 9"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, perform string concatenation operations with the `CONCAT` function

```
 ... LIKE CONCAT('%',ads.title,'%')
```

I also recommend you ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead. And move the join predicates into an `ON` clause. And consider using shorter table aliases to qualify the column references.

```
  SELECT req.id AS req_id
       , ads.id AS send_id
       , req.user_id
       , ads.des
       , ads.title
    FROM products_requests req
    JOIN ads
      ON req.title       LIKE CONCAT('%',ads.title,'%')
     AND req.ads_cat_id     = ads.ads_cat_id
     AND req.ads_sub_cat_id = ads.ads_sub_cat_id
     AND req.price_type_id  = ads.price_type_id
     AND req.province_id    = ads.province_id
     AND req.city_id        = ads.city_id
```